# Modulo in django queryset?

Tags: django

Is there already a way to select objects according to `id % 4 == 0` in django queryset ?

The only solution I found so far is to write a custom Transform since modulo seems to be supported in Postgresql but I got errors.

Here is my code:

```
from django.db.models import Lookup, Transform
from django.db.models.fields import Field, IntegerField, AutoField

class Modulo4(Transform):
    lookup_name = 'modulo4'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        return "%s %% 4" % lhs, params

AutoField.register_lookup(Modulo4)

foos = Foo.filter(id__modulo4=0)
```

And I get an error when the queryset is evaluated (with `foos.count()` or whatever):

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

refering to a django file. It seems to be due to the modulo since I manage to make the custom transform work with the [doc example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-lookups/#a-simple-transformer-example).

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't have Django 1.8 at hand to test it, but looks like you can do this using [F with annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations), like this:

```
Foo.objects.annotate(idmod4=F('id') % 4).filter(idmod4=0)
```

(Django 1.7 and earlier doesn't support using F in `annotate`)

---

For Django 1.7 and earlier you can always use [`.extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra) but it isn't very pretty:

```
Foo.objects.extra(where=["id %% %s = 0"], params=[4])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running with django 1.7 :(  (should have specified it in the question)

Comment: @stellasia updated my answer with the only method available for Django 1.7

Comment: Seems not to work with the %d params but I can do it without the option.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @stellasia sorry, that should have been just `%s`

Answer (score 0):

```
def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
    lhs, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
    return "%s %% 4 = 0" % lhs, params
```

In Django 4 which I the following line:

```
return "%s %% 4 = 0" % lhs, params
```

should be as following:

```
return "%s %%%% 4 = 0" % lhs, params
```

Because `%%%%` the string will be interpolated twice once in as_mysql and other in db cursor so for sql statement `%%%%` become `%` which is the modulus operation.
This behavior is the same in most of Django classes that offer functionality to create a custom SQL template.