# How to filter/reduce a QuerySet to every nth row?

Tags: django, django-models

I am storing time-series data from a number of sensors in a MySQL db.  Each sensor is associated with a device, and each device can have multiple sensors.

The sensors poll every 10 seconds, so for long periods (day/week/month/year), fetching the unnecessarily large dataset becomes problematic.

I would like to resample the QuerySet prior to evaluation so that it only fetches every nth row.  Is this possible?

If not, is there a smarter approach I can take?  I suppose I could figure out a where clause that matches 1/n of the possible values for the timestamp's microseconds?

```py
device_name = request.GET['device']
   device = Datalogger.objects.get(device_name=device_name)

   sensors = Sensor.objects.filter(datalogger=device).order_by('pk').select_related('type')
   sensor_models = sensors.values_list('type', flat=True)  # get all models of sensor used by this controller
   sensor_datum_types = list(SensorModelDatumType.objects.filter(sensor__in=sensor_models).order_by('sensor',
                                                                                                    'datum_type'))  # get all datatypes relating to all models of sensor used

# assign each trace (sensor/datum_type combination) an indice for the tuples (zero is used for time/x-axis)
   bulk_queryset = SensorDatum.objects.filter(sensor__datalogger__device_name=device_name,
                                              timestamp__gte=get_filter_start_time(request),
                                              timestamp__lte=get_filter_end_time(request))
   chart_traces = []
   chart_trace_indices = {}
   chart_trace_data = [None]
   chart_trace_queryset = SensorDatum.objects.none()
   next_free_idx = 1
   for sensor in sensors:
       for datum_type in sensor_datum_types:
           if datum_type.sensor == sensor.type:
               chart_trace_name = get_chart_trace_name(sensor.sensor_name, datum_type.datum_type.description)
               chart_traces.append({'sensor': sensor.sensor_name, 'datum_type': datum_type.datum_type.description,
                                    'chart_trace_name': chart_trace_name})
               chart_trace_indices.update({chart_trace_name: next_free_idx})
               chart_trace_queryset = chart_trace_queryset | bulk_queryset.filter(sensor_id=sensor.id,
                                                                                  type_id=datum_type.datum_type.id)
               next_free_idx += 1

   # process data into timestamp-grouped tuples accessible by chart_trace_index ([0] is timestamp)
   raw_data = list(chart_trace_queryset.order_by('timestamp', 'sensor_id', 'type_id'))
   row_count = len(raw_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use `.annotate()` and a modulus to only retrieve every Nth row.  [I'm using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30307823/784648) as my reference.

```
Foo.objects.annotate(idmod4=F('id') % 4).filter(idmod4=0)
```

This should return approximately every 4th row, though if you're using some other filters as well then you might not get an exact subsample, the filter might exclude a bunch of rows that would fit the modulus, so you get unlucky that the scanner your filtering for doesn't have as many id's that are a multiple of 4.  Though you mentioned you are generating a lot of rows, and for a subsample this may be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks.

Doesn't this potentially cause issue like, if the sensor count is a multiple of n or vice versa, you may end up with a problematic pattern?  Or am I misunderstanding the annotation?  

Take two sensors and even n, for example - unless a sensor poll was missed, you'd end up getting all your samples from one particular sensor and none from the other.

The annotate is an interesting option though - is it possible to use annotations in combination with order_by('id') or order_by('timestamp') to generate a facsimile of an auto-incrementing id that you can then mod-filter against?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to highlight the caveat of this approach for sampling.  If you had 4 sensors, and you wanted to sample sensor 1, then you wouldn't get any results from this approach because it would hypothetically only return samples for sensor 4.  You could possibly get around this with something like `idmod4=(F('id')+3) % 4` though.  You may want to look into this question/answer for another approach, though it seems considerably more complicated and relies on postgresql. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191865/784648

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.

Worst-case, the microsecond-as-random sample seems to be working acceptably, if not as well as an evenly-spaced approach would.