# How to subsample time series, to every n’th row in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, time

**Goal**

I'm trying to reduce the data sent to the front-end of an application by subsampling a timeseries. Initially by just taking every nth row, because I also want to optimize for speed.

**Layout**

I'm using Django 2.1.5, with a PostgreSQL backend.
The time series table is filled with measurement data every 1-15 minutes from various sensors.

```
models.py

class Measurement(models.Model):
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='measurements')
    datapoint = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Related questions**

A few resources came up around a close solution here 
[How to filter/reduce a QuerySet to every nth row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486459/how-to-filter-reduce-a-queryset-to-every-nth-row)
and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487889/11225898
which is based around annotating with 'F' like so:

```
views.py
Measurement.objects.annotate(idmod2=F('id') % 2).filter(idmod2=0)
```

This does work till a certain extent, however as the measurements are made by ~5-25 different sensors and come in every ~1-15 minutes, the id field is not consistently tracking. Just to visualize an simplified example:

```
+----+--------+------+-------+
| id | sensor | data | time  |
+----+--------+------+-------+
|  1 | A      |  432 | 10:00 |
|  2 | A      |  534 | 10:15 |
|  3 | B      | 2342 | 10:20 |
|  4 | B      |   87 | 10:25 |
|  5 | B      |    2 | 10:30 |
|  6 | B      |  982 | 10:45 |
|  7 | A      |   23 | 10:45 |
|  8 | B      |  400 | 10:50 |
+----+--------+------+-------+
```

If one now tries to filter for sensor 'A' with %2 the list only looks like

```
|  2 | A      |  534 | 10:15 |
```

while for 'B'

```
|  4 | B      |   87 | 10:25 |
|  6 | B      |  982 | 10:45 |
|  8 | B      |  400 | 10:50 |
```

**Window function**

I thought of using the [Window](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) function of Django

```
 Measurement.objects.annotate(place=Window(expression=RowNumber(),partition_by=[F('sensor')], order_by=F('time').desc()))
```

Which gives

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.
```

And this is also mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.Window.filterable)

> Defaults to False. The SQL standard disallows referencing window
>   functions in the WHERE clause and Django raises an exception when
>   constructing a QuerySet that would do that

and stems from the [SQL logical query processing](https://www.sqltheater.com/blog/cant-use-row-number-where/), which first goes through WHERE before the SELECT, so there is no way of executing this query.

**Question**

What is a reasonably fast way of sub sampling this time series to reduce the dataset? Ideally, I would pass a filter on the time and sensor

```
.filter(sensor=thisSensor).filter(time__range=(rangeStart, rangeEnd))
```

and show a subsample, of say 200, records.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do is, as your data is inconsistent,  you can either quantize data before sending or you can choose the points you want and then by regression predict missing points in js in browser

Comment: A bit more background; the datapoints are already visualised per sensor by js in the browser, so there is not need for regression to predict missing data point. Just would like to limit the data transfer to the browser (as the viz is updating every minute).

Comment: Is it real-time update, try looking to, https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/automatic-compression-over-time-with-postgresql_595157. Also, you could build your own algorithm to compress, store and retrieve from the database. This exactly how stock charts are retrived by big companies on their website. If you switch to NoSQL, cassandra,etc they have such a feature built into them.